# How do I change or remove my old YouTube custom URL?

Tags: youtube, url, customization

Attempted Steps:

1. I created a new YouTube "brand" channel.
2. I moved my library of YouTube content to this new "brand" channel.
3. I created a new YouTube/Google account, using a new, non-Gmail email, new name, new everything.
4. I made the new YouTube account the new "brand" channel owner.
5. I removed the old YouTube account as an owner of the new "brand" channel.
6. I deleted the old YouTube account.
7. I waited a week. I still couldn't change or delete the old URL from this new "brand" channel.
8. I moved my library of YouTube content to a new "user" channel for the new YouTube user account.
9. I deleted the YouTube "brand" channel.
10. I waited a week. I still can't change the new "user" channel's URL.

Whenever I visit "Advanced YouTube Settings" (https://www.youtube.com/account_advanced), it says:

> "You're eligible for a custom URL. Claim it here."

When I click there, it says:

> Get a custom URL
>
> Here's how you'll look on YouTube:
>
> youtube.com/c/OLDNAMEHERE / add a few characters
>
> Many people have the same name. Add a few extra letters or numbers to make this URL unique to you.
>
> I have read and agree to the custom URL Terms of Use. / CANCEL / CHANGE URL

No one on YouTube has this "same name". And I want to remove it anyway.

The relevant support article (https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2657968) says:

> …you can remove the custom URL from your channel and claim a new one if you want to change it. Note that once you remove a custom URL it may become free to be claimed by another creator. … You can remove a custom URL from your channel up to 3 times per year. This deactivates the URL so that it no longer directs viewers to your channel.

This is what I want. But the instructions there say:

> Sign in to YouTube and go to your 'About me' page.
>
> Select the account with your YouTube channel in the top right. You may have to click All of your Brand Accounts if your account is not in the list.
>
> Find your current custom URL under "Sites" and click edit.

There is no "Sites" text on that page.

What am I missing?

---

Now, nine days later, if I click "You're eligible for a custom URL. Claim it here.", I'm shown:

> Get a custom URL
>
> Select an option to see how you'll look on YouTube:
>
> [RADIO BUTTON] [CURRENTNAME] and a suffix of your choosing
>
> [RADIO BUTTON] [OLDNAME] and a suffix of your choosing
>
> [CHECKBOX] I have read and agree to the custom URL Terms of Use. / CANCEL / CHANGE URL

I leave the radio button on the new name, I tick the checkbox, and I click "Change URL". The next dialog says:

> Confirm custom URL
>
> Are you sure you want to change your public URL to:
>
> youtube.com/c/
>
> Once you confirm this custom URL, you can't change it again or transfer the URL to someone else. / CANCEL / CONFIRM CHOICE

There is no text input after the `/c/`, no way to add a suffix. I click "Confirm Choice", and the dialog spins a quick gif then disappears, leaving me back at the "Advanced Settings" page, which nothing changed. The console shows a 400 status code.